# TextView,Button - setting the text size with PT unit is wrong

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I've an issue when setted textsize for textview,button in my project.
All textview,button will be setted with size 40pt on base resolution is (1242x2208) (:( it's size on my PSD file that I must follow it).

But on others resolution (ex : 1600x2560), I canculate the textsize is 51.5 pt. I've checked this size on photoshop, and i saw it look good but when I builded on my phone (ex 1600x2560) i saw the text is larger.

I don't know where I failed. 
Please let me know where I'm wrong and the solution you have to resolved this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From here :

> A  single dp is a single px on a device at 160 dpi. Android uses the "density bucket" the device falls into, and multiplies a scaler to convert dp to px.

and

> A single pt is exactly 1/72 of an inch on any screen density. Android converts pt to px using the exact dpi (xdpi and ydpi) of the device's screen.

Hence the difference in size with screen densities. Try using dp instead of pt.